# [UWP]Using Frame control in PivotItem

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, template10

don't you know any uwp/winrt control for navigation within Pivot? I have pivot control with 4 pivotitems. When I have selected one of them, I need to navigate within this pivotitem. So pivot control stay on top, but in pivotitem I could navigate. Is it good to use Frame control in PivotItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to navigate within `PivotItem` then you are in the right direction. 
You can use [Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242682) in `PivotItem`. `Frame` displays [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page) instances, supports navigation to new pages, and maintains a navigation history to support forward and backward navigation.

Ref [Frame class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242682)：

> You use the **Frame** control to support navigation to **[Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page)** instances. You create as many different page types as needed to present the content in your app, and then navigate to those pages by calling the **[Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate)** method and passing in the type of the page to navigate to.

Comment: So you think it would be better to use Frame, instead of UserControl?

Comment: @JuP If you want to supports navigation, then it's better to use `Frame`. `UserControl` doesn't support navigation.